# Is there something similar to NEGATIVE_INFINITY in php?

Tags: php

I love the negative infinity value in javascript, I think it's useful and clean in many case to use it but couldn't find something similar in PHP, does it exists?

Comment: Out of curiosity, What uses does the infinity entity have? What practical applications? Infinity is not a real number and can not be numerically justified so it's simply an abstract concept.

Comment: Yes, one way to use it for example is when you want to set a default value. For example, a value that is smaller then ANY number, so, you can be sure that the first element of a loop will be for sure greater then the initial value (in a project whre values can have big variation for instance)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
-INF
```

Got it from comment at [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/math.constants.php):

> I just learnt of INF today and found out that it can be used in comparisons:
>
> ```
> echo 5000 < INF ? 'yes' : 'no';       // outputs 'yes'
> echo INF < INF ? 'yes' : 'no';        // outputs 'no'
> echo INF <= INF ? 'yes' : 'no';       // outputs 'yes'
> echo INF == INF ? 'yes' : 'no';       // outputs 'yes'
> ```
>
> You can also take its negative:
>
> ```
> echo -INF < -5000 ? 'yes' : 'no';    // outputs 'yes'
> ```
>
> Division by INF is allowed:
>
> ```
> echo 1/INF;    // outputs '0'
> ```
>
> And test for it:
>
> ```
> is_infinite(INF);   returns true
> is_infinite(-INF);  returns true
> is_infinite(1.01);  return false
> ```

Comment: Wow couldn't find it in the documentation, I need to Google better, thanks alot very beautiful answer